# Using cxf client and server plugin at the same time for grails

Tags: grails, cxf

I'm currently trying out setting up cxf soap server and cxf soap client plugin in grails.

It works well individually but I'm not able to set them up together at the same time. I get the "No services have been found." error when I try to access my wsdl endpoints. My theory is the client plugin config is overriding something that affects the server plugin.

snippet of Config.groovy:

```
//cxf server plugin config
cxf.endpoint.soap12Binding = true
cxf.servlets = [CxfServlet: '/fax/api/*']

//cxf client plugin config
cxf {
    client {
        faxApiClient {
            //used for invoking service
            clientInterface = com.synacy.whitelabel.client.fax.Api
            serviceEndpointAddress = "http://192.168.1.99:8000/fax/soap/v2.2"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Put the server configuration into the block along with the client settings:

```
cxf {
    endpoint {
        soap12Binding = true
    }
    servlets = [CxfServlet: '/fax/api/*']

    client {
        faxApiClient {
            //used for invoking service
            clientInterface = com.synacy.whitelabel.client.fax.Api
            serviceEndpointAddress = "http://192.168.1.99:8000/fax/soap/v2.2"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question, I tried that as well, but I still get the error.